# Extracting a Value from a JSON object (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, json

How would I extract the value for `pid` in Javascript?

```
{
   "payments":[
      {
         "pid":"XXX",
         "valid":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a name of this object or is this what browser prints when a request is made to a page?

Comment: Not sure. That's what it's logging when I do the following `console.log(JSON.stringify(httpResponse.data));`

Comment: Ok, now I can answer that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `JSON.stringify(httpResponse.data)`, you are basically converting `httpResponse.data` to a string with valid JSON notation. That means, `httpResponse.data` is already a valid object where you can get `pid` from.

**So:**

`httpResponse` is an object.

`httpResponse.data` is another object within `httpResponse` object.

`httpResponse.data.payments` is an array within `httpResponse.data` object.

`httpResponse.data.payments[0]` is an object which is the first child of `httpResponse.data.payments` array.

`httpResponse.data.payments[0].pid` is what you are looking for.

**Therefore:**

```
console.log(httpResponse.data.payments[0].pid); //prints "XXX"
```

Comment: Woah! You're absolutely correct. I'm actually using parse.com to make http requests and I just saw this: `data <Object>
The parsed response body as a JavaScript object. This is only available when the response Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or application/json.` Thanks Arman!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON object.

If payments is an array then you can retrieve pid with : `myObj.payments[0].pid`

If payments is an object then you can retrieve pid with : `myObj.payments.pid`

Comment: Yup, `payments` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your json was not a valid jason your json should be look like this.

```
Object={
payments: [{pid: "XXX",valid: 1},{pid: "XXX",valid: 1}]
}
```

and once your json will be like this.

then you can read json as.

```
Object.payments[0].pid
```

which will give you value of pid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {
  "payments":[
    {"pid":"XXX"},{"valid":"1"}]
}

console.log(a.payments[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.payments[0].pid
```

and if the JSON were to have multiple payments in it's array you could use:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myObject.payments.length; i++){
    myObject.payments[i].pid
}
```